OpenSSH - Change privilege separation directory
I'm trying to install OpenSSH from compiler and in a different location than usual. I need to change the "privilege separation directory" but I can't find where to configure this. I've done some research and it's possible it's in the binary. If anyone knows if I can change it somehow that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

I found the solution. I'm sharing it in case anyone else needs it.
It turns out that the option to add "PrivilegeSeparation sandbox_directory=/path" in the sshd_config file is deprecated. I suppose it could be changed in the binary itself, but instead now exists the " --with-privsep-path" parameter that you can use when running ./configure. Example: "./configure --with-privsep-path=/path".
